Handling absolute urls when serving an existing app at a subpath
I want to serve a pre-existing javascript app inside my flask app. For example, I want to serve the home page for the javascript app at the route GET /my_app_1/.
Then, when the app loads resources, if those resources are specified as relative path/to/my/resource I can capture them easily because the request to the server will be /my_app_1/path/to/my/resource.
However, I don't know how to handle the case where the app's resource is specified as an absolute /path/to/my/resource. Then the request to the server will be /path/to/my/resource and it will escape the /my_app_1 prefix, right?
What would be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Is it necessary to edit the existing app and rewrite all the absolute urls to be relative?
